# how to restrict facebook graph search to cities only

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

We're have a web-app that uses Facebook connect and is using FB graph via JS & http. We want to enable the user to publish a post on his timeline that will include a city pinpoint location map. Facebook Docs says [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#posts) that for the 'place' parameter in creating posts, I need to write the Facebook Page ID, which I want the user to pick from a list (otherwise how will i get the page ID right?...) so for instance Londone, I should use - [210582665626133](https://www.facebook.com/pages/London-United-Kingdom/210582665626133), so I assume I need to use - graph.facebook.com/search?q=london&type=place to get a json lookup of places.
this brings me to my question - How can I restrict search results to show only cities?
If there isn't a way to specify this as a parameter on the graph call, and assuming I'd have to filter those on the client, then what is the category or any other method to spot a city out of the clutter of irrelevant places?
cheers :)

Comment: And do you want cities all over the world?

Answer (score 1):

The information for Facebook places is pretty random. Most of the categories are user-generated, so you never really know what you're going to get.

For instance, then I run your search above, I never get the id `210582665626133` returned in my results, even with a limit of 500.

Personally, were I approaching this, I'd use the [Factual Places API](http://www.factual.com/data-apis/places) to find the relevant places, then use the [Factual Crosswalk API](http://www.factual.com/data-apis/places/crosswalk) to find the matching Facebook IDs, and only then start querying Facebook.

Comment: +1 I din't know the existence of Factual Places, I'm going to add this to my bookmarks

Comment: I read about this a year ago. It seems that they provide Facebook with a lot of their place data.